# Proper JSON type definition to import with a runtime module struct with other struct and enum

Tags: substrate

I have the following data type defined in my runtime module

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum AuctionStatus {
  Ongoing,
  Cancelled,
  ToBeClaimed,
  Closed
}

// This is necessary so that other structs depend on this enum can be encode/decode with default value.
impl Default for AuctionStatus {
  fn default() -> Self { AuctionStatus::Ongoing }
}

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Auction<Hash, Balance, Moment, AuctionTx> {
  id: Hash,
  kitty_id: Hash,
  base_price: Balance,
  start_time: Moment,
  end_time: Moment,
  status: AuctionStatus,
  tx: Option<AuctionTx>,
}

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct AuctionTx<Hash, AccountId, Balance, Moment> {
  auction_id: Hash,
  tx_time: Moment,
  buyer: AccountId,
  tx_price: Balance,
}
```

**Now in polkadot UI, what should be the correct JSON type definition to be imported?**

I tried the following but polkadotUI is still saying unknown type.

```
{
  "AuctionStatus": "u32",
  "AuctionTx": {
    "auction_id": "Hash",
    "tx_time": "Moment",
    "buyer": "AccountId",
    "tx_price": "Balance"
  },
  "Auction": {
    "id": "Hash",
    "kitty_id": "Hash",
    "base_price": "Balance",
    "start_time": "Moment",
    "end_time": "Moment",
    "status": "AuctionStatus",
    "tx": "Option<AuctionTx>"
  }
}
```

**Update-01**:

The following are the browser console error messages:

1st message:

```
Unable to decode storage catAuction.auctions: createType(Auction):: Encoding for input doesn't match output, created 0xa9531feb7f4eb8a888e1eedf72e812e26e32a53a2e379ef79bb2e8f7d883f2462e1cd9ea24d53ce565292a9e56458943554c7c13b6aef70c00079076650bdd8f983a0000000000000000000000000000f6491c5d0000000060ce1e5d00000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 from 0xa9531feb7f4eb8a888e1eedf72e812e26e32a53a2e379ef79bb2e8f7d883f2462e1cd9ea24d53ce565292a9e56458943554c7c13b6aef70c00079076650bdd8f983a0000000000000000000000000000f6491c5d0000000060ce1e5d000000000000
```

2nd message:

```
2019-07-03 14:24:40        RPC-CORE: subscribeStorage (keys: Vec<StorageKey>): StorageChangeSet:: createType(Auction):: Encoding for input doesn't match output, created 0xa9531feb7f4eb8a888e1eedf72e812e26e32a53a2e379ef79bb2e8f7d883f2462e1cd9ea24d53ce565292a9e56458943554c7c13b6aef70c00079076650bdd8f983a0000000000000000000000000000f6491c5d0000000060ce1e5d00000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 from 0xa9531feb7f4eb8a888e1eedf72e812e26e32a53a2e379ef79bb2e8f7d883f2462e1cd9ea24d53ce565292a9e56458943554c7c13b6aef70c00079076650bdd8f983a0000000000000000000000000000f6491c5d0000000060ce1e5d000000000000
```

not sure if this give any help...

Comment: Can you please share the specific error given by the UI?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi updated the questions with error messages shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is you have defined your enum as a `u32` and it is messing up parsing the encoded data.

From the Polkadot UI help text:

> Be aware that the types are registered in the order they appear here.
>   Since Transaction above requires both TransactionInput and
>   TransactionOutput it is defined after the definitions for those are
>   available. (Circular deps are not supported here). For a slightly more
>   complex example, using both types and enums, the following would be
>   used -
>
> ```
> {
>   "SimpleEnum": {
>     "_enum": ["One", "Two", "Three"]
>   },
>   "TypeEnum": {
>     "_enum": {
>       "One": "u32",
>       "Two": "u64",
>       "Three": null
>     }
>   }.
>   "MyNumber": "u32",
>   "Thing": {
>     "count_enum": "SimpleEnum",
>     "type_enum": "TypeEnum",
>     "counter": "MyNumber",
>     "ids": "Vec<AccountId>"
>   },
>   "ArrayThing": "Vec<Thing>"
> }
> ```

So try defining your enum correctly and see if that resolves your issue. Let me know if this helps.